# Swift: Properties are not being added to ProductName-swift.h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have these properties in my .swift class.

```
class values : NSObject {

var username: NSString?
var title: NSString?
var longValue : Int64?

}
```

However, the long value isn't being added into my ProductName-Swift.h file that is used to import swift code into my Objective C code. Can someone please help me to understand why this is occurring and how to resolve it? The NSString properties are being added into the file however, just not the Int64 property.

Comment: Hmm odd. Have you tried using just an Int instead?

Comment: What will happen if you remove `longValue` declaration from the class?

Comment: @Aggressor same issue.

Comment: @MaxK Nothing happens.

Comment: @WayneSlayer, what do you mean 'nothing'? It compiles or not?

Comment: @MaxK He means that it compiles without any errors/warnings, but `longValue` is omitted from the `-Swift.h` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift optional integer cannot be represented in Objective-C. Either don't make it optional, or use `NSNumber`.

Comment: Thanks, this is happening with me when I'm making methods from swift type optionals.